# Remote Desktop barely any load but network connection is really slow

Tags: remote-desktop

We currently have a solution that consists of:

2 RD Gateways, 2 RD Connection Brokers and Licencing Servers and 4 RD Session host machines.

2 of the RD Session host machines seem to connect and work fine but there are 2 that seem to be really slow to connect to and I can't pinpoint why.

We use these to serve a RemoteApp.

Here is what I have checked:

1. Checked Load - Nothing concerning
2. Check running programs - Nothing concerning
3. Check perfmon - Nothing concerning
4. Temporarily stopped antivirus - No effect
5. Restarted affected session hosts - Was fine for a little while, then regressed back
6. Rebuilt the session hosts affected - Was fine for a little while, then regressed back
7. Compared between the 2 affected and non affected session hosts - No differences from what I can see

These machines are Windows Server 2019 machines running on AWS EC2. I have ensured that there is adequate resources allocated to the machines. Given that the load isnt high, I am sure resources is not the issue.

Any ideas?